# Solve inequality with exponential

Tags: derivatives, inequality, finance

I recently need to solve the following equation:

$e^{\frac{-A_1^2}{2c^2}}+1>e^{\frac{-A_2^2}{2c^2}}$

where $A_1=ln(K_3/K_1), A_2=ln(K_3/K_2)$ They are actually strike prices (in finance) so $K_1<K_2<K_3$, and c is a positive constant term

What condition can make the inequality correct?

I have really no idea as I cannot take log, and I am not sure how to use derivative to solve them
But there is a hint to consider concavity with this equation.

Comment: Is $0 < e^{-x^2} \le 1$?

Comment: Yes. You are right! I should specify this